# How to use rpmbuild to build a rpm package from binary tarball?

Tags: fedora, rhel, tar, rpm, rpmbuild

Resources on Internet are all about how to build a rpm files from source code.

But I have already got compiled binary tarball of software. But I don't want to directly extract it to `/` , because it is difficult to maintain. How can I build a rpm package from binary tarball.

There is a series famous software which provided the binary package in a tarball which have a clearly tree structure which is same as the tree structure in root dir.

- [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org)
- [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info)

And so on.

A lot of software provider release universal tarball to make the software universal in different Linux distribution.

Is there a essential way?

Comment: You can use the old pkgtool2 to write a spec file. Then run `$ rpmbuild -bb scilab.spec` in your rpmbuild environment https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13 ... to build an rpm pagkage. Link, `pkgtool2-2.2.3-4.i386.rpm` : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQ0ZEbHB1V1BUa0E/view?usp=sharing → Install pkgtool2 with `# yum install ./pkgtool2-2.2.3-4.i386.rpm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPD** Thanks to @msuchy who has corrected me.

Assume that you've already created a 'rpmbuild' directory skeleton in your home directory: SPECS, BUILD, SOURCES... Copy the tarball into the SOURCE directory and write simple spec-file, skipping the sections: %prep, %build.

Little example:

Tarball:

```
[yurij@centos7 SOURCES]$ ls -lah
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user  33 Mar 12 12:22 .
drwxrwxr-x. 8 user user  89 Dec  8 15:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 231 Mar 12 12:14 binarius-0.1.tar.gz
[yurij@centos7 SOURCES]$ tar -tvf binarius-0.1.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x user/user       0 2018-03-12 12:11 ./binarius-0.1/
drwxrwxr-x user/user       0 2018-03-12 12:11 ./binarius-0.1/usr/
drwxrwxr-x user/user       0 2018-03-12 12:11 ./binarius-0.1/usr/local/
drwxrwxr-x user/user       0 2018-03-12 12:12 ./binarius-0.1/usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x user/user      30 2018-03-12 12:12 ./binarius-0.1/usr/local/bin/binarius
```

Spec-file:

```
Name:       binarius
Version:    0.1
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Binarius package

Group:      System Environment/Base
License:    GPLv3+
Source0:    binarius-0.1.tar.gz

%description
Testing package.

%prep
%setup -q #unpack tarball

%build

%install
cp -rfa * %{buildroot}


%files
/*
```

Comment: It is better to have `%prep\n  %setup -q \n\n %install \n cp -rfa * %{buildroot}`. Rest of the answer is correct.

Comment: In Centos 7.4, macro '%setup -q' force trying './configure' step. Therefore, I omit it.

Comment: Yurij - definitely not true. See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html

Comment: I've tested spec with '%prep', '%setup'. You are right. I knew that macros '%prep', '%setup' must not to do configure step. '%configure' macro exists for that. But, when I was writing and testing spec for this example, configure step was executing after any changes in spec file. When I've  commented all macros except '%install', I've got package. It's hard to assume what happed, but now it's work. Maybe I was not so close. Thanks for correction! I've edit answer.

Comment: Usually, if I'm not sure about macro, then I read 'rpmbuild --showrc' output. In my answer I've forgotten to do this.